# How to add an image into this responsive CTA to the left?

Tags: html, css

I'm an amateur coder but trying to educate myself a bit more.

I have a CTA (Call to action) that i'd like to have an image in.

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  background: #ff0000;
  grid-template-columns:  2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1080px;
}

.grid img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .griditem {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .griditem p {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .griditem h3 {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.griditem {
}

.griditem p {
  color: #fff;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    align-self: right;
    margin: 0 0px 0 20px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #00243d !important;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 7px 17px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="griditem">
<h3>
Upgrade the smart way.
</h3>
<p>
Trade in your unwanted tech and use the cash to buy or rent your next device!
</p>
</div>
<div class="griditem">
<p class="button">
button
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qnu82prm/

I'd like the image to the left of the h3 and p if that makes sense.

Attempted various things but can't quite work out what is best to do.

Answer (score 0):

This code should place an image to the left, using "float: left" so the text knows how to flow around the image, and center the picture when below 500px.

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="grid">
<div class="griditem">
<h3>
<img src="https://praestocreative.com/images/pic1.png" class="hero" alt="pic">
```

Upgrade the smart way.

Trade in your unwanted tech and use the cash to buy or rent your next device!

button

```
<!-- css -->
.grid {
 display: grid;
 background: #ff0000;
 grid-template-columns:  2fr 1fr;
 grid-gap: 10px;
 padding: 20px;
 align-items: center;
 max-width: 1080px;
 }

/*.grid img {
  max-width: 100px;
} */

.griditem {
 border: 0 solid #966;}

.griditem p {
  color: #fff;
}

.button {
 display: flex;
 float:right;
 width: 100px;
 align-self: right;
 margin: 0 0px 0 20px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #00243d !important;
 font-size: 1.05em;
 font-weight: 700;
 border-radius: 3.5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 line-height: 40px;
 padding: 7px 17px;
 justify-content: center;
}

.hero {
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
 display: block;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .griditem {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .griditem p {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .griditem h3 {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hero {
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 float: none;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto 10px auto;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/976dzbvw/2/